# SSIS API page-based pagination

Tags: ssis, pagination, kingswaysoft

I am trying to setup an SSIS package that calls a certain API. I have watched several YouTube videos, read documentation on this process. In short, the API does not provide any columns such has `pages_left` or `hasMoreData`. The max count I can pull is 100. Problem is there is WAY more than 100 records per authorization token that I have.

What is a good way to loop and hit all of the data I need? I have 20ish different authorization tokens. My last resort would be to create loops with `?page=0, ?page=1,` upwards to 75 pages per token.

Example JSON data:

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "Active": true,
    "FirstName": "string",
    "LastName": "string",
    "JobTitle": "string",
    "EmployerId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "StreetAddress": "string",
    "City": "string",
    "PostalCode": "string",
    "MobileNumber": "string",
    "PhoneNumber": "string",
    "DateHired": "2023-07-25T17:31:54.832Z",
    "EmployeeNumber": "string",
    "EmergencyContact1": "string",
    "EmergencyContact2": "string",
    "EmergencyNotes": "string",
    "CreatedOn": "2023-07-25T17:31:54.832Z",
    "LastModifiedOn": "2023-07-25T17:31:54.832Z",
    "Email": "string"
  }
]
```

Attached is a screenshot showing my JSON Source Editor. I didn't know if there would be anything to put into the Request Again Rule that doesn't result in endless looping.

[image: JSON Source Editor]

I am at a loss as to what I can do without creating separate loops that explicitly hit the different pages.

Comment: You should be looking at using the Request Again Rule option at the bottom of the screen. You could bring up the expression window if you click on the fx button.